# parameter with class type variable

Tags: c#

I  have TWO CLASSES now while initializing the Order class I have to pass the data to the constructor, but the constructor takes `CartContents` type data what does it mean, what to pass to the parameter. I don't understand this concept.

```
//first class

public class CartContents 
{
    public CartEntry[] items;
}

//second class

public class Order 
{
    private CartContents cart;
    private float salesTax;

    public Order(CartContents cart, float salesTax) 
    {
        this.cart = cart;
        this.salesTax = salesTax;
    }

    public float OrderTotal() 
    {
        float cartTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cart.items.Length; i++) 
        {
            cartTotal += cart.items[i].Price * cart.items[i].Quantity;
        }
        cartTotal += cartTotal * salesTax;
        return cartTotal;
    }
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Order OrderObj = new Order(new CartContents(), 12.5);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Order class has a custom Constructor:

public Order(CartContents cart, float salesTax).

This means that whenever you instantiate Order class,you need to pass an object of type CartContents and a object of type float as parameters to the Order Class.

In the Main Method from your example you can clearly see that when instantiating an Order object you pass the CartContents type and a float type. The parameter "new CartContents()" is infact the constructor of the CartContents, so you pass the constructor as a new parameter to the Order class, and you can see that in the CartContents class you initialize an array named "items" of type CartContent

Please see the following links regarding Constructors in C#:

EDIT: Fixed links

1) [Instance Constructors in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx)

2) [Using Constrctors in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)